# Search for latest version of jar file in folder and run it from batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I created a simple batch file to run jar server file. It is two lines of code:

```
cd /D %~dp0
java -jar server-0.17.0.jar
```

The problem is the server file is updated every while and hence script either fails to run the correct version or fail to run.

My request is, is there anyway to replace server jar file with latest released by number or date dynamically?

I'm only aware that I can retrieve available jar files using:

```
dir *.jar
```

But have no idea how to concatenate the command with the katest version. Thanks

Comment: you can try it like this. create a file list into a file like this dir (star-char)server(star-char).jar /O:D >server.jar.txt then you have a list of the server files ordered by date, then you can readin the file and take only the first line, this should be the latest server.jar . I am writing this on my mobile device, hope this helps....

Comment: Whoever installs a new version of the .jar file should update the script. Alternatively, they should install it under a version-less name, e.g. `server.jar` or `server-latest.jar`. Whether they do that instead-of or in-addition-to installing with the version-named file is up to you. If in-addition-to, you could make the version-less name a soft link instead of a copy, which is very likely what you'd be doing on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try a script like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b server*.jar') do set latestjar=%%x
java -jar %latestjar%
```

Second line in this script will set the *latestjar* to the last created file whose name compliant with **server*.jar** template.

Comment: dir /od /b server*.jar : This command lists the files in the current directory in sorted order by date (/od) without heading(/b). **for /f** loops through the output of the dir command and assigns the file name(output of dir and held in placeholder %%x) to **latestjar**. As the last file listed will be the newest file after loop finishes latestjar has the newest file name as value.